# FSharp Charting on Deedle series how to plot two series into one chart

Tags: f#, deedle, fsharpchart

I have following F# script code:

```
    #load "packages/FsLab.1.1.6/FsLab.fsx"
    #load "packages\FSharp.Charting.2.1.0\FSharp.Charting.fsx"
    open Deedle
    open FSharp.Data
    open FSharp.Charting
    open Deedle.Series

    ...

    Chart.Combine
     ([Chart.Line(tmp1?Close |> Series.observations),
       Chart.Line(tmp1?Open |> Series.observations)])
```

The last three lines open two chart windows rather than one combined one with both `tmp1?Close` and `tmp1?Open` plotted. How do I get one combined plot?
And in general, how do I plot the Deedle Frame all columns at once like    `Chart.Line(tmp1...`?

**EDIT** one note for the down voting and the accepted answer: although `;` would work, but all the examples online replace the `,` with empty space but it will get error

```
error FS0597: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized
```

Therefore I thought this question still have limited positive value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need a `;` or nothing instead of the comma?

I think `Combine` takes a `seq` of series as an argument, whereas the comma means you're passing a tuple.